# Given Pitch and Roll in one Heading, convert to co-planar pitch and roll for North

Tags: control-theory, aerospace-engineering, positions-measurement

I have been pouring through countless articles about Euler's angles, rotation matrices, Rodriguez Rotation Formula, Quaternions, trying to understand how to generate an algorithm for this problem and have as of yet been unsuccessful.  I am trying to figure out, given a pitch and roll along a particular heading, the manner in which one could determine the co-planar  pitch and roll along the magnetic North heading.

[image: Reference Image Showing concept]

In the above image, I have the pitch and roll values at the currentHeading, and am trying to calculate the pitch and roll values of the blue line in the same plane but in the magnetic North direction.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't specify a unique 3D rotation for a single line.

Comment: @fibonatic: Rotate the body around the Yaw axis, so that projection of the Pitch axis onto the XY plane is rotated by angle of -heading; give new Pitch and Roll. (Yaw axis is not explicitly given, but can be determined using Pitch, Roll and Heading)